Twenty Twenty Four Theme - Image and text same height?
I have a simple page with two columns using the Twenty Twenty Four theme.
First column has 1 paragraph with a background color.
Second column has 1 image.
The List View looks like:
Columns
   Column
      Paragraph
   Column
      Image

How can I make the Paragraph and Image always have the same height regardless if the paragraph is smaller or larger than the image?
Really hope to do it without using a plugin.

This is most likely a CSS solution but we'd need to see the mark-up to be able to advise.
